# Windows 10: Change account type without signing out?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, user-accounts

I am trying to write a script to automatically change my account type every week for a few hours.

- I know this can be done via the following, however I want to finalize the change without having to sign out and in again:

  ```powershell
  Net LocalGroup "Administrators" "Tom" /Add
  ```

Is this possible via command line?

Comment: "I want to finalize the change without having to sign out and sign in again. Is this possible on the command line?" - No

Comment: You’re not changing the account type. It’s still a user account (as opposed to a group or other special principal types). You’re adding or removing group memberships (and thereby permissions).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way of changing account type while being logged in, both from command line and GUI. But one thing I guess (Untested) is to create a temporary Administrator account and or use existing Administrator account to `runas` command to run `net localgroup Administrators Tom /add` as the Administrator account without logging out.